# nodejs XHR calls stop after around 50 calls

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, deferred

I'm using the XHR nodejs module to do a lot of ajax calls (around a 100 now). I do this async using deferred. This works really well until the amount of requests passes somewhere around the 40 to 50 calls. Then it simply stops and does nothing indefinably. If I do in in sync(which isn't really an option) it does support all the calls i can through at it. So what it causing this problem?

My code is as followed:

```
    function getFile(url) {
        var def = deferred()
        ,xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

        xhr.open("GET", url); 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
        //Callback
        function handler (){
            // If status is ready
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300 || this.status === 304) {
                try {
                    var result = eval(this.responseText);
                } catch (e) {
                    def.resolve(e);
                }
                def.resolve(result && result[0]);
            } else if (this.status === 401){
                console.log('Error 401')
                def.resolve(new Error('Error:' + this.responseText));
            };
        };
        xhr.send(null);
        return def.promise;
    };
```

If I console.log the status I keep getting a nice status 200.

I'm calling the getfile() with the following code snippet:

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, fs = require('fs')
, XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest
, promisify = require('deferred').promisify
, deferred = require('deferred')
, readdir = promisify(fs.readdir)
, exists = promisify(fs.exists)
, writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile)
, filepath = './public/movies/config/moviefiles.js'

    // Set max of events to unlimited
    req.setMaxListeners(0)
    readdir(configfileResults.moviepath).map(function (file) {
        var filename = file
        , year = longregex
        , movietitle = verylongregex
        if (year == null) year = ''
        var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/"+configfileResults.language+"/json/apikey/"+movieTitle+"?year="+ year +"?="
        return getFile(url)(function (ajaxResult) {
            return {
                movieTitle:movieTitle,
                filename: file,
                movieScraperInfo: ajaxResult
            };
        });
    })(function (data) {
       return writeFile(filepath, JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }).end(function () {
        // Download Cache
        downloadCache()
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Failed", e);
    });
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

As Brad suggested I added a lot of console logs.

```
function getFile(url) {
    var def = deferred()
    ,xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    console.log("url:", url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log("status ready");
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300 || this.status === 304) {
                try {
                    var result = eval(this.responseText);
                    console.log('getting files', i++)
                } catch (e) {
                    def.resolve(e);
                }
                console.log("resolving files");
                def.resolve(result && result[0]);
            } else if (this.status === 401){
                console.log('Error 401')
                def.resolve(new Error('Error:' + this.responseText));
            };
            console.log("not ready");
        };
        console.log("out of callback");
    xhr.open("GET", url); 
    xhr.send(null);
    return def.promise;
};
```

The result:

I get 60 "url:", url logs showing all the urls needed to get the data.
Then, the callback is being executed.

resulting in:

getting files 3
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 4
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 5
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 6
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 7
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 8
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 9
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 10
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 11
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 12
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 13
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 14
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 15
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 16
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 17
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 18
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 19
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 20
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 21
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 22
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 23
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 24
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 25
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 26
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 27
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 28
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 29
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 30
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 31
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 32
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 33
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 34
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 35
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 36
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 37
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 38
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 39
resolving files
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
not ready
status ready
getting files 40
resolving files
not ready

Ending in de 'not ready'.

Can anyone shed a light on this?
See the code on github:

https://github.com/jansmolders86/mediacenterjs/blob/master/apps/movies/index.js

Comment: How often are you calling `getFile(url)`? Can you post the calling code?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was.
I was doing to much at the same time, keeping data in the memory while passing it on to other functions. In other words, I simply ran out of memory. I'm going o refactor the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't make sense. Can you clarify what is going on here?

```
return getFile(url)(function (ajaxResult) {
        return {
            movieTitle:movieTitle,
            filename: file,
            movieScraperInfo: ajaxResult
        };
    });
```

Comment: I use Deferred https://github.com/medikoo/deferred to run all the processes async and finally write all the data to one json file. That's why the code you've highlighted is not in the fucntion(data) callback. Ontherwise it would create multiple files.

Comment: Maybe this will help you make sence of it all: https://github.com/jansmolders86/mediacenterjs/blob/master/apps/movies/index.js

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what is going on. My intuition tells me you are creating too many ajax requests simultaneously and "locking" the browser, something similar to doing `setInterval(ajaxRequest, 100)`. My suggestion is to insert lots of console.log/warn/error in your callback functions and trace what is going on right before the ajax requests start failing. I'm sure as soon as you do this, the problem will become as clear as day.